# I am getting wrong value from sqlite table in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am getting wrong value from sqlite table. this is my code

code :

```
    var arrtribute_Mast_List : NSMutableArray = []
    var querySQL = String(format:"SELECT * FROM %@ ORDER BY %@", TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_MASTER, ATTRIBUTE_MASTER_ATTR_ID)
    var statement:COpaquePointer = nil
    //querySQL =   querySQL.String(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, querySQL, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            let name  = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)
            let attributeName = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(name))
            println("Attribute value = \(attributeName)")
         }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }
```

I am getting output:

```
   Attribute value = Optional("Shamitabh")
```

Need Output :

```
   Attribute value = "Shamitabh"
```

Comment: Can't you unwrap the optional? Your output and what you want for output are basically the same anyway, just that the first one is optional.

Comment: In My Table Column Value is "Shamitabh" . But I am getting Optional("Shamitabh") like that

Comment: Do you know what an optional value is? What unwrapping an optional value is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `Optional("Shamitabh")` because `String.fromCString` is not guaranteed to succeed. It may fail, and `attributeName` will be nil. You can resolve this by either making it an implicitly unwrapped optional (which will crash if `String.fromCString` fails):

```
 let attributeName = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(name))!
```

.. or you can do it right and check if the value is nil before using it. For example, like this:

```
 if let attributeName = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(name)) {
      println("Attribute value = \(attributeName)")
 } else {
      println("Couldn't get the attribute name")
 }
```